# Laravel 4: Add a filter to a route a pass it a controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

How to you add a filter to a route and pass a controller to it?.

In Laravel's doc they said that you can add a filter to a route like this:

```
Route::get('/', array('before' => 'auth', function()
{
     return 'Not Authorized';
}));
```

But I need to pass a controller, like this:

```
Route::get('/', array('before' => 'auth', 'HomeController@index'));
```

But I get this error when I do it like that:

```
call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, no array or string given
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should pass the controller function with `uses` key, So replace,

```
Route::get('/', array('before' => 'auth', 'HomeController@index'));
```

With,

```
Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', 'before' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index'));
```

And there should be a route for login to process the `auth` filter like this.

```
Route::get('login', function()
{
   if(Auth::user()) {
      return Redirect::to('/');
   }

   return View::make('login');
});
```

Comment: Can I ommit the `as` parameter in the array?

Comment: Is there a way to return a controller with a method, instead of `return View::make('login');` ?

Comment: You can use the same way. ``Route::get('login', array('uses' => 'HomeController@login'));`` and return the view from ``HomeController``'s ``login`` function.

Comment: I've just noticed a whitespace `' uses'` that throws me the same error, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Wanted to add another solution to your problem.

You can also use this, which in my opinion feels more readable.

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->before('auth');
```

You only need to use "as" and "uses" if you're in need of named routes, eg. for a Form route.